# Latest three twitter feeds for my website

Tags: jquery, html

I just wonder how to get the latest three twitter feeds.
Here is my code, but this will show all the feeds instead of three.Can anyone suggest me how to get latest three twitter feeds.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">  </a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry: use data-tweet-limit like `<a class="twitter-timeline" href="//twitter.com/githubstatus" data-widget-id="479252841396056064" data-tweet-limit="2" data-chrome="nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent">
     Tweets by </a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=githubstatus">@githubstatus</a>
` Taken from: https://blog.twitter.com/2014/3-power-tips-for-using-embedded-timelines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to limit tweets in Twitter timeline widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995777/is-there-any-way-to-limit-tweets-in-twitter-timeline-widget)

Comment: Thank you..got solution. Itz working:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for latest 3 twitter post

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-lang="en" data-dnt="true" data-tweet-limit="3" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev">Tweets by TwitterDev</a> 
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
```

I hope this will work cause the attribute `data-tweet-limit` is set to 3 latest posts